# Implementing a service in android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, android-service

I take below sample in net searching.  I implemented the sample with some modification, but it shows error after rebooting the phone.  I also pasting source code i used in the sample, please help me to solve problem

thanks in advance

**xml file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.newtest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  
<application>  
    <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>  
    <service android:name=".BackgroundService"/>  
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Broadcast receiver class**

```
package com.example.newtets;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {  
           Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
           context.startService(pushIntent);  
    }
}
}
```

**service class**

```
package com.example.newtets;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BackgroundService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onCreate();
}

}
```

Comment: what error u are getting plz also add log with question

Comment: I can't get log (i don't know how to get log for service application that executes after booting the phone), after rebooting the phone, the application crashes with unexpected error

Comment: Why are you setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK if you are starting a service and not an activity?

Comment: simply remove `pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` the line and your task will be fine

Comment: i removed the line, but still error occurs

Comment: you have to check which intent call when RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in log after that you can use it in manifest & receiver. otherwise this code not work. search this que in google you get same problem very time. so check your device log when RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: iam a newbie, how to check log ?

Comment: Use LogCat in Eclipse or `adb logcat` from the command line to access crash logs, complete with stack traces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need to compare the intent..

```
if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {  
 .....
}
```

as, it is captured in the xml file that BootCompletedIntentReceiver should be executed for BOOT_COMPLETED intent.